# Get first N elements in 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to access first N elements of a 2D array, Going sequentially through the elements and jumping into the next arrays as needed.

I do not know the sizes of the second dimensions, but I do know the size of the 2D array with a previous method and can assume the array has enough elements fit my request of the first N elements.

I could build a function myself, but with my familiarity with JS there could well be an standard library command or best practice for it.

What is the most elegant method of doing this?

Comment: No, there's nothing built in that does that for you. You just do it yourself, with `for`, or `Array#forEach`, or `Array#some`, or `Array#reduce`...

Comment: Tags don't go in titles, that's why we have tags. Nor is making the first sentence of your question a tag useful.

Comment: I see. I will have to use standard `for` since I don't want foreach to run past the whole array when I only need a couple of elements.

Comment: That's why I mentioned `Array#some`, you can stop it.

Comment: I read up on it and I cannot imagine how I would use it to stop a forreach. If you explain it with an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: You wouldn't "use it to stop a `forEach`". You'd use it **instead of** a `forEach` (since you can return `true` out of the callback to stop a `some` loop).

Comment: Ahh I understand.The predicate would test if the given amount of elements have been read.